# Blank page on startup

Tags: android

Before getting my splash screen I get a blank page for a little time (<1s) when I start my application. I even tried with an almost empty splash `Activity` but I still get it!

What's wrong?

**Manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**SplashActivity.java**

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
}
```

**splash.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**

I tried with a default project and I still have the issue. Help!

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blankpage.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.blankpage.test.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**SplashActivity**

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**splash.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity" 
    android:background="#654456">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try putting `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in manifest instead of `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in activity?. That was causing issue in my app.

Comment: @Anamika yes, same issue

Comment: Ok. still shows blank screen?

Comment: Yes... That's the only issue I have

Comment: Just thought I'd leave this here: http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Comment: What device are you testing this on?

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib : Nexus 4 and 7

Comment: Can you please download http://www.mediafire.com/?2fh99pl2gs42njq and get the `splash.apk` file in the bin folder and try to install it and test if you get a similar behavior. You can also try `splashmovie.apk`. Let us know.

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib : There is a short delay too, but might be because of the video loading...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I did.

==> After digging a lot I found that the Delay was caused by "Theme" aspect in Manifest file.

So , I created my own Style Based on some really helpful example from web(Source I really frogot) .

My suggestion to you would be to add these Lines in your res/values/styles.xml :

```
<resources>
    <style>
        ------- 
    </style> 

    <style name="SplashScreen">
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And in your Manifest file Just pass that as style Under Your Activity tag as :

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.sai.splashactivity.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

May be this will help you.

Comment: I am Glad , It Worked for you too!

Answer (score 1):

It does take time for creating views. and moreover if you want to just display image your code should be like

```
   <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

1) You do not need a ViewGroup as there is only one widget.

2) Make sure your image which you are setting in background is not too large in size. Provide proper image. It will load fast. Because if your background image is e.g. of 2MB, processor need time to draw on screen.

Comment: I even tried without the `ImageView`. I still get the blank page.

Comment: Remove scaleType, it does will execute some image scaling code while creating background. Just provide proper sized image with proper resolution, by that only you can minimize the loading time.

Comment: Also you can use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" in Activity Tag in manifest file to avoid that black color.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

**splash.xml**

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added this:

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

to my custom style in styles.xml.